# Remote conenction to mysql server database from wamp windows

Tags: mysql, wamp

I'm developing a website that needs to conenct from localhost(windows WAMP) to a remote mysql server. The remote mysql server is aleady enabled to allow remote connection to my ip and all work fine on my (tested on mac os and linux machine).
On windows my scripts are able to access to mysql servers on localhost or local network but can't access the remote server. I've also disabled the firewall but nothing happen.
Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: show your code and also tell what error are you getting

Comment: I'm using joomla for the website, so I'm using the joomla api. Simply windows seems to block the connection from apache to the remote db. The same code work on linux machine

Answer (score 10):

This is a typical firewall issues if you are using Windows OS particularly windows 7 or 8.

Disabling your firewall from the Antivirus on your server (where your wamp is installed) might not help.

follow this steps:

1. Go to the control panel of your Server (wamp server PC)
2. Go System and Security
3. Choose Windows Firewall
4. Choose Advance Settings
5. Choose Inbound Rule
6. Choose New Rule - New Inbound Rule Wizard will pop up
7. Choose Port and click next
8. Choose TCP and click next
9. Enter 80, 3306 (These are default ports respectively for Apache and Mysql servers on wamp) if you have changed them on your wamp server PC then indicate the appropriate ports
10. Choose Allow the Connection
11. Check or uncheck whether you will allow this ports on Private, Public or Domain Network
12. Give the rule a name and click finish

Answer (score 0):

In your Joomla sites root folder there is a file called `configuration.php`

In there are lots of config params but these are what you need to check for this situation

```
public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'joomla25user';
public $password = 'joomla25pass';
public $db = 'joomla25';
public $dbprefix = 'j25_';
```

Specifically you need to check

```
public $host = 'localhost';
```

This should be changed to the *ip address* of the server running this *remote MySQL server*

Comment: Hi, I know very well joomla, the configutation file it's ok, the same site with the same configuration run on my linux machine. Also, sinse I need to connect to a remote database the ip address in my configuration is the remote server ip (the mysql server and the mysql user are enabled to access emote conenction). The problem is that windows do not allow my local scripts to access to the remote database.

Comment: Could this be a firewall issue then?

Comment: I've also disabled the firewall with no success..:(